# How to implement Fully Convolutional Networks (FCN) with arbitrary-sized input size in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In [Fully Convolutional Networks for Semantic Segmentation](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf) the authors write:

> Fully convolutional versions of existing
>   networks predict dense outputs from arbitrary-sized inputs.

I can't see how a Keras model can support arbitrary-sized images.

```
from keras import models
from keras import layers

input_image = layers.Input(shape=(None, None, 1))

b = layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu')(input_image)
b = layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(b)
b = layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu')(b)
b_out = layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(b)
flattened_out = layers.Flatten()(b_out)
output = layers.Dense(10*10, activation='sigmoid')(flattened_out)
output = layers.Reshape((10,10))(output)
```

Also when I am looking at other FCN implementation on github like [this one](https://github.com/JihongJu/keras-fcn#fcn-with-vgg16) I see they do state a specific input size:

```
fcn_vgg16 = FCN(input_shape=(500, 500, 3), classes=21,  
                weights='imagenet', trainable_encoder=True)
```

Can someone help me to build a simple FCN in Keras?

Comment: Yes, it can be built, but the model you showed is not fully convolutional, it has a Dense layer. What is the actual problem you are having?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I am looking for an example how to have a network that can handle any input dimension without interpolating the picture before feeding it into the NN. Or a simple example of FCN in Keras.

Comment: You can modify `FCN(input_shape=(None, None, 3), ...)` and it should work.

Comment: @0x90 did you learn how to do this?  Matias is correct.  You have a dense layer which makes your example not fully convolutional.  As you pass larger images, the outputs (aka feature maps) from the convolutional layers will grow too.  This will cause an error when your network flattens a larger dimensional vector than the input size to your Dense layer.  In case that's not clear, the dense layer input size is FIXED, which conflicts with passing in larger images which would produces VARYING output sizes.

Comment: Don't use dense layers and use None to allow arbitrary input side.